# Generating styled element for use by external sites

Tags: html, css

In one of our web applications we are needing to allow a user to generate a "button" which they can place on their website that will send users to our application. The idea sounds simple enough but the more I think about it, I'm not sure what the best route would be for accomplishing this. One option I have come up with would be to generate a hyperlink around an image that's hosted on our server, something like:

```
<a href="/location/on/our/application">
    <img src="//ourapp.com/images/button-image.jpg" />
</a>
```

Our app uses bootstrap and what we're really looking for is just a basic bootstrap button. Something like:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/location/on/our/application">To Our App</a>
```

However, this obviously will not have the desired effect when the client site is not using bootstrap framework.

I have always steered clear of iframes, however could this be an instance where their usage would be acceptable? Is there another option I have overlooked?

Comment: You can add the css to the element as inline styles. https://www.codecademy.com/articles/html-inline-styles

Comment: I didn't think you could use css features such as :hover, :focus, etc in inline css? If so then, yeah this is a good option.

Comment: You are correct. I had not considered that aspect.

Comment: Your probably better off providing them with a link to a remote javascript file. This can then append an IFRAME. The advantage of this is that you can update it and you're not competing with their css. It can also be updated in the future if you roll out to alot of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to go down the route of a CSS button, I would recommend inline styles. Considering you have no idea what stylesheets the external websites are using, you need to bundle your own styles, and inline styles are perfect for this. They have the second-highest level of **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**, second only to the **[`!important` declaration](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)**. What's important to note is that you can in fact combine `!important` with inline styles:

```
<div style="display: block !important;"></div>
```

This cannot be overridden in any way, and is guaranteed to display as is intended... assuming the external website developers honour those rules, and don't modify the HTML / CSS you supply to them (which you can't be assured of).

As such, images will be the best solution, as there **cannot** be any 'distortion' by the owners of the external websites; either the image is outright replaced entirely or it is not.

Ultimately, aside from brand imagery protection, all you really need to worry about is that the **[`href` attribute](https://html.com/attributes/a-href/)** still points to your website (along with passing through any required **[query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)**). As long as that's valid, the link is just as valid as a fully-formed button in terms of conversion rates or any other metrics you might be interested in.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: My only hangup with this solution would be the :hover event, which could be emulated by changing the css properties with javascript using `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events on the element I suppose...this might be the way to go.

Comment: Again, you cannot control what the developer of the external website does; they are completely free to remove any CSS / JS you supply them. The benefit to using an image is that they don't have access to the image's domain (in order to modify it). While purely aesthetic, if you insist on a `:hover` effect, supplying them with either CSS or JS would essentially carry the same caveats; neither one would be more beneficial than the other. If anything, I'd simply supply the `:hover` CSS and hope that they use it (because `!important` overrides JavaScript, as JavaScript uses inline styles) :)

Comment: I see what you're saying now. We shouldn't worry too much about what what we're supplying as long as they have the most important part, the link, since there's a good chance they will modify it to their liking anyway. We will probably go the route of supplying the link and corresponding css in a `<style>` block. If they use it, great. If not, they can modify how they wish it to appear. Appreciate the input!